# Wrapping a text around a circular element

Tags: css, css-float

I have 2 DIV's as shown below and I've been trying to get the text between the two circles to wrap around the inner circle as shown on the attacthed image. I have not been able to achieve the desired result.

**HTML**

```
<div id="outer-circle">

This is just a test logo name    

    <div id="inner-circle">

    </div><!-- End Inner Circle -->

</div><!-- End Outer Circle -->
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#inner-circle {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    margin-top: 28px;
    position: relative;

}

#outer-circle {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 100%;
     background-color: blue;
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align center;
    text-align: left;

}
```

[Click here to see current but undesired result](http://jsfiddle.net/sleek/sFuLC/24/)

**Example of desired result**
[image]

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/set-text-on-a-circle/

Comment: Frankly, sometimes an image is the way to go. No real need to overthink things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**See [this post by Chris Coyier](http://css-tricks.com/set-text-on-a-circle)** in which he separates each character of text into `<span>`s and rotates each one in turn using CSS rotation:

```
.char1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(6deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(6deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(6deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(6deg);
  transform: rotate(6deg);
}
.char2 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(12deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(12deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(12deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(12deg);
  transform: rotate(12deg);
}
...etc
```

Or **use [Dirk Weber's csswarp.js Service](http://csswarp.eleqtriq.com/)** which pretty much does the same but uses javascript to generate the html and css for you. ([csswarp.js on GitHub](https://github.com/dirkweber/csswarp.js))

Or use SVG text on a path as in [this example from useragentman.com](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2013/05/20/cross-browser-svg-text-paths-without-javascript-even-in-older-ie/)

```
<svg id="myShape" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <path id="path1"
          fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"
          d="M 212,65
             C 276,81 292,91 305,103 361,155 
               363,245 311,302 300,314 286,324 
               271,332 248,343 227,347 202,347 
               190,346 174,343 163,339 143,333">
    </path>
  </defs>
  <text id="myText">
    <textPath  xlink:href="#path1" >
      <tspan dy="0.3em">C is for Cookie, That's Good Enough For Me!</tspan>
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Or...

**Use an image.**

Comment: is there a way to appease the SEO gods even if we use an image of circular text so that it can be aligned, etc easier?

Answer (score 1):

Use base info from https://css-tricks.com/set-text-on-a-circle/
BUT with a simplifications and without any additional libs.
And it will work with any text you type...

```js
var lettering = function(node,text){
    var str = typeof text=='undefined'
        ?node.textContent
        :text;
    node.innerHTML='';
    var openTag = '<span>';
    var closeTag = '</span>';
    var newHTML = openTag;
    var closeTags = closeTag;
    for(var i=0,iCount=str.length;i<iCount;i++){
        newHTML+=str[i]+openTag;
        closeTags+=closeTag;
    }
    node.innerHTML = newHTML+closeTags;
}
lettering(
    document.getElementById('text'),
    Math.round(Math.random()*1000) + ' : Hello world!!!'
);
```

```css
.badge {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(-50deg);
}

h1 span {
  font: 26px Monaco, MonoSpace;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
  transform: rotate(10deg);
}
```

```html
<div class='badge'>
<h1 id="text">Any custom text you type...</h1>
</div>
```