# Curved Text inside a circle and center to bottom center

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a circle, and i need to have text inside the circle, that follows the circles path. I have found this other question: [Wrapping a text around a circular element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23811276/wrapping-a-text-around-a-circular-element)

However, i was not able to achieve what i'm trying to do. My text has a dynamic length, and i need it to be always centered to the bottom center of the circle, and wrap "upwards" on both sides, if that makes sense. I have tried the svg approach, but when the text is too long, it gets cut off. What would be the best approach to do this?

[image]

The text would be orange here (dynamic length), and it needs to centered to the bottom of the circle (blue dot)

Comment: Simple way is create text by path with svg, check [css tricks example](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/svg/curved-text-along-path/)

Comment: What do you want to do when the 'text is too long' - some calculation to shrink the text size so that it fits or do you want to increase the circle size to fit?

Comment: The max length of the text will be set so that it will always fit the circle. So worst case scenario, the text would wrap around the whole circle, with a small space between end and start.

Comment: @Greg--

I have used that method. However, when used together with startOffset and text-anchor (to center the text), the text gets cut off at some point. I think this might be due to the svg path, but i don't know svg well enough, to manipulate it. Ofcourse, if there is no other way, i'll have to learn it. I'm just looking around if there is another way to achieve this.

Comment: Here is a fiddle of my current implementation using SVG. As you can see, the text gets cut off when it's too long.
https://jsfiddle.net/5ujLb03t/

Answer (score 2):

Having tried positioning text with middle in the svg I found it cut the text if the text was following a path - as in the question.

Could not find a solution for this in SVG and/or CSS so resorted to a method with JS and show it here just in case of use as an interim measure.

In this snippet, the width of the text is found and the amount the SVG needs to rotate in order to put the mid point of the text at the bottom center of the circle is calculated:

```js
const textPath = document.querySelector('textPath');
const temp = document.createElement('div');
temp.innerHTML = textPath.innerHTML;
temp.style.display = 'inline-block';
temp.style.fontSize = '20px';
document.body.append(temp);
const w = temp.offsetWidth;
document.body.removeChild(temp);
const circumference = Math.PI * 200;
document.querySelector('svg').style.transform = 'rotate(' + Number((180 * w / circumference) - 90) + 'deg)';
```

```css
.qr--label {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0 0 -15px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="qr">
  <div>
    <svg width="220" height="220">
      <path fill="white" d="M0,110a110,110 0 1,0 220,0a110,110 0 1,0 -220,0"/>
      <path fill="none" id="innerCircle" d="M10,110a100,100 0 1,0 200,0a100,100 0 1,0 -200,0"/>
       <text>
         <textPath  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#innerCircle" class="qr--label">
             Some dynamic text here
           </textPath>
         </text>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```